# Symfony2 Form with Doctrine Relationship Persistence Issue

Tags: doctrine-orm, relationship, symfony-forms, persist

So I have 3 entities with their properties.
A USER which has MANY USERSKILLS with each ONE having a single corresponding SKILL

Here are the entities:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="skills")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Skill
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=30, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="active", type="boolean")
     * @var bool
     */
    private $active = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserSkill", mappedBy="skill")
     */
    private $userSkills;
}


/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_skill")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class UserSkill
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="skills")
     * @var User
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Skill", inversedBy="userSkills")
     * @var Skill
     */
    private $skill;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var int
     */
    private $level = 0;
}

/**
 * StartupDriven\UserBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="StartupDriven\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserSkill", mappedBy="user")
     * @var ArrayCollection
     */
    private $skills;
}
```

They are created using 2 symfony form objects which works fantastically.

The problem is when I go to persist these objects in the controller.... I get an error

```
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {

    /**
     * @var User $user
     */
    $user = $form->getData();

    /**
     * @var UserSkill $userSkill
     */
    foreach ($user->getSkills() as $userSkill) {

        // No updating skills... Only new ones.
        if (!$userSkill->getId()) {

            // Check skill name match.
            if ($matched_skill = $em->getRepository('StartupDrivenUserBundle:Skill')->findOneBy(array('name' => $userSkill->getName()))) {
                $userSkill->setSkill($matched_skill);
            }
            else {

                // No match. Create new generic skill.
                $em->persist($userSkill->getSkill());

                // THE ERROR HAPPENS ON THE FOLLOWING LINE!
                $em->flush();
            }

            // Set the User
            $userSkill->setUser($user);

            // Persist the user skill.
            $em->persist($userSkill);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }

    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
```

Error Message:
`A new entity was found through the relationship 'StartupDriven\UserBundle\Entity\User#skills' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: StartupDriven\UserBundle\Entity\UserSkill@0000000053e8628e00007f7f2fd56e1f. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'StartupDriven\UserBundle\Entity\UserSkill#__toString()' to get a clue.`

I have tried every combination of persist & flush that I can think of. I have tried the cascade option above (which gives a different error that the "user id which is required by the primary key rules is not set")... I am completely lost. It seems like such a simple relationship... Where am I going wrong?